# NPM fetch failed

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

Here's a quick one:

```
npm install socket.io

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/socket.io-0.9.10.tgz
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/socket.io-0.9.10.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/-/socket.io-0.9.10.tgz
npm ERR! Error: 404 Not Found
npm ERR!     at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/fetch.js:47:16)
npm ERR!     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
npm ERR!     at WriteStream.flush (fs.js:1514:12)
npm ERR!     at fs.close (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:92:5)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/enrico/Documents/MMORPG
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.48
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/enrico/Documents/MMORPG/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

what's wrong with this npm install? is the server unreachable? Any workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://twitter.com/addy_osmani/status/234565967101972481 <-- see this conversation. I think many people are having trouble today :/

solution: https://github.com/mmalecki/npm-proxy <-- NPM proxy

or use: `npm install <module> --registry http://165.225.128.50:8000`

Comment: you can count me in. i was trying to npm update for around 2 hours till the bell in my head told me to google this issue.

Comment: so sad.. seems like that private registry is getting squeezed like a sponge.

Comment: seems like that registry has too many file handles open to handle more requests. gah.. i just want to install emailjs