# Heroku Deploy Getting 404 Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

We are trying to deploy an app to heroku and having some issues with the MongoDB dependency returning a 404 error.

I ran into the same problem earlier, I believe the resource was updated or down before. Here is the npm log we get from heroku.

```
   git push heroku master
   Counting objects: 107, done.
   Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (93/93), 255.39 KiB | 61 KiB/s, done.
   Total 93 (delta 43), reused 0 (delta 0)

   -----> Heroku receiving push
   -----> Removing .DS_Store files
   -----> Node.js app detected
   -----> Resolving engine versions
          Using Node.js version: 0.8.6
          Using npm version: 1.1.41
   -----> Fetching Node.js binaries
   -----> Vendoring node into slug
   -----> Installing dependencies with npm
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.0.0rc1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo/-/connect-mongo-0.1.9.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.0.0rc1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.0.0rc1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs/-/ejs-0.8.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.3.3.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-mongo/-/connect-mongo-0.1.9.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express/-/express-3.0.0rc1.tgz
          npm WARN package.json connect-mongo@0.1.9 No README.md file found!
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-3.0.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/-/underscore-1.3.3.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs/-/ejs-0.8.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-3.0.1.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.4.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.4
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crc/0.2.0
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.0.3
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.4.1
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-2.4.1.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.4
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/-/cookie-0.0.4.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.3.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/crc/0.2.0
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crc/-/crc-0.2.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/-/range-parser-0.0.4.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mongodb-0.9.9-8.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.0.3
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-0.7.0.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.0.3.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/-/methods-0.0.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/-/connect-2.4.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.3.3.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/-/cookie-0.0.4.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/-/fresh-0.1.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/-/commander-0.6.1.tgz
          npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mongodb-0.9.9-8.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/-/methods-0.0.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/-/send-0.0.3.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-0.7.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/crc/-/crc-0.2.0.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/0.2.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.1.2
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.1.0
          npm WARN package.json connect@2.4.1 No README.md file found!
          npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mongodb-0.9.9-8.tgz
          npm ERR! Error: 404 Not Found
          npm ERR!     at null.<anonymous> (/tmp/node-npm-oliq/lib/utils/fetch.js:47:16)
          npm ERR!     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:115:20)
          npm ERR!     at WriteStream.flush (fs.js:1514:12)
          npm ERR!     at fs.close (/tmp/node-npm-oliq/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:94:5)
          npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
          npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
          npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
          npm ERR! or email it to:
          npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

          npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
          npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-0RqS/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-oliq/cli.js" "install" "--production"
          npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1kq3xko4hyz59
          npm ERR! node -v v0.8.6
          npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.41
          npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.1.0
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/0.2.1
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.1.0.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/-/hooks-0.2.1.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb/1.1.2
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mongodb-1.1.2.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.4.2
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.11
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.1.0
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-0.1.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hooks/-/hooks-0.2.1.tgz
          npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mongodb-1.1.2.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.11
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/-/formidable-1.0.11.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
          npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mongodb-1.1.2.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.6.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.1.0
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/-/bytes-0.1.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.4.2
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/-/pause-0.0.1.tgz
          npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.4.2.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/-/formidable-1.0.11.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.6.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/-/bytes-0.1.0.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-0.4.2.tgz
          npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/-/pause-0.0.1.tgz
          npm ERR! 
          npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
          npm ERR!     /tmp/build_1kq3xko4hyz59/npm-debug.log
          npm ERR! not ok code 0
    !     Failed to install --production dependencies with npm
    !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently a wide-spread problem with npm hitting 404 errors:

[NPM fetch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922430/npm-fetch-failed)

Comment: Yes I found out that NPM was actually down, and we were in a competition yesterday. I found this GitHub thread: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2694