# How to check if a particular npm package is working?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running

> `$npm install`

to install the dependent packages out of a `package.json` file, but some packages in particular are failing to install.

Since [npm's status page](http://status.npmjs.org/) seems to be for npm in general, is there any way to check the status of a particular package?

Comment: Can you post the error/warning messages?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté an example is: `npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/filesize/-/filesize-1.7.9.tgz`

Comment: `npm install filesize@1.7.9` works fine for me. Maybe it is a problem with your network/gateway/proxy?

Comment: Could be. Since there's some other packages failing. Is there a way to check the status of the package without having someone else try to `install` them?

Comment: The URL which reportedly failed to fetch should be fetchable through the browser too. https://registry.npmjs.org/filesize/-/filesize-1.7.9.tgz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed my work blocked certain packages, possibly based on the name, or throttling, whatever. At home they worked fine. You'll have to get around your proxy since the error that you're getting back is the indication that the package is not loading. The NPM status page is where to go to make sure npm is still serving up packages, so you had that right.

Since it was the entire fetch that failed, I would guess that's your main issue (access via proxy).

Here is more on NPM and proxy issues: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2119

and how one person fixed it: ["message failed to fetch from registry" while trying to install any module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/installing-from-npm-fails)

If you can't access the registry (NPM down), then you could also try the direct IP approach: [NPM fetch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922430/npm-fetch-failed)